# Jupyter notebook kernel keeps on dying inside the docker container

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook

I tried running my configured python project inside a docker container called climatebench. I try to run Jupyter notebooks inside the docker container, but the kernel keeps on dying every time, I have tried providing good amount of resources (all the cpus and 20GB memory)
but the kernel still keeps on dying. Could anyone suggest how to resolve it ?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem running a Jupyter Notebook Container under Docker Desktop on Windows. Problem was that the default location for images is the systemdrive even if docker desktop is instlled on another drive. When no memory was left on the systemdrive the kernel stopped. The solution was to move the docker desktop default location to a drive with enough space.

If you are running on another plattform this may be unrelated. But checking where the docker image etc is actually saved and if there is enough space left may be a good staring point.